# Add div fade-out in React with SCSS and conditional rendering of div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I currently successfully fade-in a conditionally-rendered `div` in React using SCSS/SASS `mixin` and `keyframes`.

I'd additionally like to add fade-out functionality to the `div` after it's closed. I tried dynamically changing the class of the div (`className={div_enable?"div_in":"div_out"}`), but the problem is, the events that change the conditional rendering to `false`/dismisses the `div` (in my example below, pressing `Enter` when the `div` is in focus) are the same actions that change its class to `div_out`. The conditional rendering gets triggered first, so the `div` completely disappears before the fade-out `div_out` class can be applied.

How can I retain my conditional rendering logic for the div while adding fade-out functionality when the `div` is dismissed?

**Update**: I found the possibility of [using `OnAnimationEnd`](https://dev.to/oussel/how-to-use-conditional-rendering-with-animation-in-react-1k20), which I think would be easiest to implement without needing to overhaul my code. However, I'm not sure how to translate the tutorial's Functional Component code to my project's Class Component code.

I also found the possibility of [using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`](https://blog.prototypr.io/using-reactcsstransitiongroup-for-enter-exit-animations-ea100d68e72f). The linked tutorial uses a React Class Component and I'm slowly trying to chip away at it and transcribe it to my code below. However, I'm afraid implementing `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` into my actual project (not seen here) will require quite a major overhaul so would prefer getting something like `OnAnimationEnd` to work.

[CodePen with working SCSS/fade-in](https://codepen.io/wad11656/pen/LYWLQmx)

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = { div_enable: false };
  }
  submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ div_enable: true }, () => this.myRef.current.focus());
  };
  closeModal = () => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && event.shiftKey === false) {
      this.setState({ div_enable: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { div_enable } = this.state;
    return (
      <div content>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <input
            id="text_entry"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter text"
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        {div_enable && (
          <div
            className={div_enable?"div_in":"div_out"}
            onKeyDown={this.closeModal}
            tabIndex={0}
            ref={this.myRef}
          >
            <p>Press Enter to make me disappear.{" "}
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
@mixin fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

@mixin fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}

.div_in {
  @include fade-in;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
}

.div_out {
  @include fade-out;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable a CSS exit animation for your conditionally-rendered elements, you can remove the SCSS altogether and convert your conditional render declarations (e.g., `{my_condition && ... }`) to `<`[`CSSTransition`](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition)`>` tags--while making sure to include the [`unmountOnExit`](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-unmountOnExit) prop within the tags (which prop is inherited from `CSSTransition`'s parent component, [`Transition`](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition))--like so:

**Old**:

```
// Javascript
{div_enable &&
 <div className={div_enable?"div_in":"div_out"}>
     <p>My paragraph</p>
 </div>
 }
// CSS
/* [See original question] */
```

**New:**

```
// Javascript
{
 <CSSTransition
 in={div_enable}
 timeout={200}
 classNames="fade"
 unmountOnExit
 >
     <div className="div_in">
         <p>My paragraph</p>
     </div>
 </CSSTransition>
}
// CSS
.div_in {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
}
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

**Full Code** (I couldn't get [importing ES6 modules (`{CSSTransition}`) in StackOverflow's editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406233/3511695) to work, so the StackOverflow code below doesn't run):

[Working CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/wad11656/pen/oNZeRej)

```js
import {CSSTransition} from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-transition-group/4.4.1/react-transition-group.min.js";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      text_exists_enable: false,
      text_empty_enable: false,
      text_field: "",
    };
  }

  textEntered = (event) => {
    this.setState({ text_field: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.text_field !== "") {
      this.setState(
        {
          text_exists_enable: true,
        },
        () => this.myRef.current.focus()
      );
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          text_empty_enable: true,
        },
        () => this.myRef.current.focus()
      );
    }
  };

  closeBlueBox = () => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && event.shiftKey === false) {
      this.setState({
        text_exists_enable: false,
        text_empty_enable: false,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { text_exists_enable, text_empty_enable } = this.state;
    return (
      <div content>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter text"
            onChange={this.textEntered}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        {
          <CSSTransition
            in={text_exists_enable}
            timeout={200}
            classNames="fade"
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <div
              className="div_in"
              onKeyDown={this.closeBlueBox}
              tabIndex={0}
              ref={this.myRef}
            >
              <p> Textbox HAS text! </p>
            </div>
          </CSSTransition>
        }
        {
          <CSSTransition
            in={text_empty_enable}
            timeout={200}
            classNames="fade"
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <div
              className="div_in"
              onKeyDown={this.closeBlueBox}
              tabIndex={0}
              ref={this.myRef}
            >
              <p> Textbox is EMPTY! </p>
            </div>
          </CSSTransition>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.div_in {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-transition-group/4.4.1/react-transition-group.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```